# How do I append Altitude Integers

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, mapkit, cllocationmanager

I need to display the current Altitude in a current app I am building. However, when the Altitude is determined, the label gets displayed with xxx.xxxxxxxxxxxx
It goes super far on the other side of the decimal point. I only want it to give a at most, 2 numbers on the other side of the decimal point. How is this possible?

```
    manager.delegate = self
    manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    manager.startUpdatingLocation()

     func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager,            didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    let location = locations [0]

    self.speedLabel.text = String(location.speed)


    self.altitudeLabel.text = String(location.altitude)
    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location) { (placemarks, error) in

        if error != nil {
            print(error!)

        }
```

That is my current code.

Like I said, I only want to display the Altitude as, "XX.XX" and not XX.XXXXXXXXX

Comment: Use `NumberFormatter`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
extension Double {
    func decimal(places: Int) -> Double {
        let resultString = NSString(format: "%.\(places)f" as NSString, self) as String
        return Double(resultString)!
    }
}
```

self.altitudeLabel.text = location.altitude.decimal(places: 2)

Answer (score -2):

Just try:

```
self.altitudeLabel.text = String(format: "%.2f", location.altitude)
```

Comment: Learn to do localization properly. Use `NumberFormatter`.